# Не удаётся поставить ревьювера в Merge Request (GitLab)

Tags: gitlab

Платформа - GitLab. При выборе ревьювера в Merge Request никого не находит из пользователей при поиске. А при выборе Assignees - предлагает только меня. В настройках меняла только приватность проекта (потом его всё же сделала публичным).

Answer (score 0):

Решила тем, что добавила нужного пользователя в Reporter проекта. Затем стал доступен в Merge Request.